# Azure App Service - Securing function with two B2C policies

Tags: azure-functions, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c, azure-web-app-service

We have a function, running in Azure App Service handling authenticated calls, via Easyauth for user accounts that are hosted in an Azure AD B2C tenant.

These accounts were previously self-served, via a B2C **built-in** SignUp&SignIn policy. We’re moving to an invitation only model and we’ve implemented a B2C SignIn_Only **custom policy** based on the Microsoft samples.

My question is specifically around App Service configuration. In the Authentication/Authorization settings, we have App Service authentication turned on for our function. The ‘Action to take when request is not authenticated’ is set to ‘Allow Anonymous requests (no action)’. The Azure Active Directory Provider is configured with the client ID of our function and the intended audience is set to our mobile app. The *issuer URL* is set to:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{OurTenantName}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={OurBuiltinSignUpSignInPolicy}

With this configuration, requests from users signing in using the builtin policy work fine, but users signing in with the custom policy are returned **401 Unauthorized** errors. Conversely, if we change the issuer URL to point to the new Signin_Only custom policy, requests from users signing in using the new policy work fine, but sign-ins using the builtin policy fail with the 401 errors.

I’ve tried this using both the login.microsoft.com and {ourtenant}.b2clogin.com endpoints with the same result. I’ve also inspected the JWT tokens and everything looks ok. Of course, the issuer is different but everything else including the signing keys looks right.

Is it possible to support users signing in via **both** builtin and custom policies? Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I knew, we cannot use builtin and custom policies in Azure function. Because the builtin and custom policies have different issuer metadata. such as jwk. Therefore we will get the different access token signature with the two policies. However, we just can provide one metadata endpoint in Azure function. So, the function just can accept the access token with the policy you configure.

For example
My builtin policy  jwk
[image]

My custom policy jwk
[image]